# Sorting a multidimensional array while keeping its arrangement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort this array but at the same time,  I am trying to change the index and all elements unchanged.

I want to sort the array by [name]. So array[7] with `Cross Cutting Functions` would be the first node and so on ...

### This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 992
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Global People
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1206
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Global Department Head
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 1
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 986
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Global Private Leaders
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 2
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1208
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Service Line Partnership
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 3
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 984
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Digital Stakeholders
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 4
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 990
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Regional Team
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 5
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 988
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Digital Team
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 6
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1210
            [vid] => 70
            [name] => Cross Cutting Functions
            [description] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [weight] => 7
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

### This is what I tried:

(But it's not working)

```
 foreach ($terms as $key => $row) {
      $temp_array[$key] = $row['name'];
 }

array_multisort($temp_array, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `$temp_array` be the second array? And what's the difference between `$terms` and `$data`?

Comment: `array_multisort` reindexes numeric arrays.

Comment: So do you want the `objects` inside **$terms** to change order? or do you want the `elements inside the objects` to change order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use PHP `usort` to solve this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
// Example with your $terms
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}

usort($terms, "cmp");
```

Comment: `usort()` assigns new keys.

Comment: _I am trying to change the index and all elements unchanged_ - He wants the index changes but the values the same ? I don't see the issue

Comment: he wants the order of the array to change, but the indexes to stay the same. So index `7` will be the first element of the array.

Comment: Well it looks like we're understanding the question differently. I don't see what changing the order of the elements inside the `$terms object` will accomplish. But I can see how changing the order of `$terms` would be useful. Need @Steve to clarify I guess

Comment: Changing the order affects things like `foreach`.

Comment: But it's a standard object.. he can still access the variables using `$object->name / $object->parents`. We will just wait for clarification

Comment: I mean `foreach ($terms as $i => $term)`. This should return `$i = 7` first, the `$i = 4`, and so on.

Comment: It's perfect man!